# Unable to read Windows file even when it has "Read" permission set through java

Tags: java, windows, permissions, java.nio.file

I am trying to set permissions for a file to the Administrators group from java in windows.
Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

 final Path path = Paths.get("C:/Dev/dummy/test"); 
 FileAttribute<?> permissions = new FileAttribute<List<AclEntry>>() {
    public String name() {
        return "acl:acl";
    }
    public List<AclEntry> value() {
        try {
            return get600ACL(path.getFileSystem());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
 };

  Files.createFile(path, permissions);
```

}

```
private static List<AclEntry> get600ACL(FileSystem fileSystem) throws IOException {

List<AclEntry> aclEntryList = new ArrayList<AclEntry>();
 AclEntry.Builder acl3 = AclEntry.newBuilder();
 acl3.setPermissions(EnumSet.of(
         AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_ATTRIBUTES,
         AclEntryPermission.SYNCHRONIZE, AclEntryPermission.READ_ACL, AclEntryPermission.READ_ATTRIBUTES, AclEntryPermission.READ_NAMED_ATTRS,
         AclEntryPermission.DELETE, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS, AclEntryPermission.APPEND_DATA, AclEntryPermission.EXECUTE, AclEntryPermission.DELETE,
         AclEntryPermission.DELETE_CHILD, AclEntryPermission.ADD_FILE, AclEntryPermission.ADD_SUBDIRECTORY, AclEntryPermission.LIST_DIRECTORY, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_ACL,
         AclEntryPermission.WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA, AclEntryPermission.WRITE_OWNER
 ));
 GroupPrincipal grp2 = fileSystem.getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByGroupName("Administrators");
 acl3.setPrincipal(grp2);
 acl3.setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW);
 AclEntry entry3 = acl3.build();
 aclEntryList.add(entry3);
 return aclEntryList;
}
```

[After creating file, the permissions are proper as seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tes60.jpg)

But when I create a new user, give him Administrator permissions and try to open the file, it says user has no read permissions.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash added complete code. Yes I am getting as Path file = Paths.get("c:/test.txt");

Comment: Since Vista (2006), administrators are UAC restricted, which means they're logged on with two tokens -- a standard-access, medium-integrity-level token and an administrator-access, high-integrity-level token, and the standard-access token is what gets returned and used for interactive sessions. Getting administrator access requires elevating using a system service such as the Appinfo service (e.g. "run as administrator"). Getting admin access via runas.exe or the underlying `CreateProcessWithLogonW` API function is not possible, unless the account is excepted from UAC restriction.

Comment: @ErykSun Thankyou for the response. When I manually tried to "run as administrator", it worked. I assumed if the user had Administrator rights, he will be able to access directly. My mistake :)

Comment: Run `whoami /groups /fo list` in a non-elevated command prompt to see the user's groups and the attributes of each group. Note that Builtin\Administrators (S-1-5-32-544) is used for deny only, which means it's in effect only for DENY ACEs in the DACL, not for ALLOW ACEs. Try again in an elevated command prompt. In this case the administrators group is enabled for all ACEs, as well for setting it as the owner of objects.

Comment: @ErykSun thanks for the inputs. I will try that. I have one more query. I have given only read permission to Administrators group. But the members are able to delete the file. I want them to only able to read the file but not delete. On searching I found that "The only way to prevent file deletion is to not give read permissions and explicitly deny Delete permission." Is that true? Is there any permission settings I can give to make Administrators group to only read but not delete the file? Thanks in advance

Comment: In your example, you're granting administrators full control of the file. In practice whether you need to use a deny entry depends on which groups are set explicitly in the DACL and what access the entries grant and whether inheritance is enabled. But for `DELETE` access, in particular, it's not enough to allow or deny it for an individual file. You also need to control `DELETE_CHILD` access for the parent directory, which overrides `DELETE` access set on individual files in the directory.

Comment: @ErykSun yes, in above example I gave full control just for testing but in actual code, I only gave "READ" access. I have disabled Inheritance for this file. Even then should I control DELETE_CHILD option of parent directory?

Comment: Yes, you must control `DELETE_CHILD` access on the parent directory, which may entail creating a subdirectory that you're allowed to modify. This is a file-system policy, not a matter of inheritance. When the file system tries to delete the file, if the handle lacks delete access it will allow it anyway if the parent directory grants delete-child access.

Comment: Bear in mind, with these DACL changes, that you're only making it inconvenient for an administrator to delete the file. An admin can still modify the DACL or enable SeRestorePrivilege to get delete access anyway. To go further to prevent this you can keep the file open in a background app or service without delete-access sharing. Then an admin will have to terminate the process in order to get delete access. But this is really over the top. Administrators should be trusted to do the right thing.